# How does OpenGL std430 layout align elements in an array?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, memory-alignment

I have a PointLight struct in C++

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
  glm::vec4 position; // 16 bytes
  glm::vec4 color;    // 16 bytes
  float intensity;    // 4 bytes rounded to 16 bytes?
  float range;        // 4 bytes rounded to 16 bytes?
};
```

usage in ssbo:

```c
layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer lightSSBO
{
  PointLight pointLight[];
};
```

Will the float elements be rounded up to 16 bytes due to the vec4s?
Does std430 always round elements in an array to the size of the largest element?

Will I need to add padding to my struct to correctly access the variables?

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
  glm::vec4 position; // 16 bytes
  glm::vec4 color;    // 16 bytes
  float intensity;    // 4 bytes
  float range;        // 4 bytes
  float padding[2];   // padding to make struct multiple of 16 bytes, because
                      // largest element vec4 is 16 bytes
  // total 48 bytes
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. (see https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=166&zoom=100,168,308) from rule 9 and 10 for `std430`: If the member is an array of S structures, the base alignment of the structure is N, where
N is the largest base alignment value of any of its members.
In the case of `std140`, this would be rounded up to the basic alignment of a `vec4`. I case of `std430` is is not rounded up. However, since the largest element in your case is a `vec4`, this makes no difference in your case.

Comment: How does it make no difference if the rule does not apply to std430?

Comment: @Dave For `std140` is is rounded up to `vec4`. In case of `std430` it is not rounded up. But in your case the `largest` element is already `vec4`.

Comment: So for an array, std430 always rounds to the largest element?

Comment: @Dave Yes, as clearly stated in the specification.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for clarifying. I'm not well versed with reading specifications